# Easy approach to add a label to images using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a folder with approx 30 pictures in it. I now want a way to easily identify the pictures so each picture should get a label on it from 1 .. 30

I want to use ruby for this and use available resources on my mac rather than any third party libraries.

I could probably get this to work using ImageMagick and I will post this here if I finally have to do that. But I wonder if there is a more light-weight approach.

Ideally I should be able to style this in terms of font-size, text-weight and maybe even some shadow and borders if this is doable.

Comment: What kind of picture format are you using? Anyway, I think you won't be able to accomplish this without using some external library. What is the reason why you don't want to use third party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go for a 3rd party library, give [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) a try. It's a very easy to use wrapper around ImageMagick. I've used it for resizing and watermarking pictures uploaded to a website of mine. =)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but i used to use RMagick and added watermarks on my images. RMagic is a wrapper around image magic and it is very easy to use http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/